# Angular/rxjs: livesearch heroes tutorial - why use an observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Could you tell me the advantage in using an Observable for `heroes$` in Angular's livesearch tutorial? (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)

Or in other words, is there something "wrong" with using a regular object instead of an observable at all in this particular example?

Original example 1 - with Observable:

```js
export class HeroSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes$!: Observable<Hero[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService,
    private http: HttpClient) {}

  search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroes$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((term: string) => this.heroService.searchHeroes(term)),
    );
  }
  
  searchHeroes(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {
    if (!term.trim()) {
      return of([]);
    }
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${'api/heroes'}/?name=${term}`)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="search-component">
  <label for="search-box">Hero Search</label>
  <input #searchBox id="search-box" (input)="search(searchBox.value)" />

  <ul class="search-result">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes$ | async" >
      <a routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">
        {{hero.name}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Version 2 without Observable:

```js
export class HeroSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes!: Hero[];
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService,
    private http: HttpClient) {}

  search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchTerms.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((term: string) => this.heroService.searchHeroes(term)),
    ).subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }
  
  searchHeroes(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {
    if (!term.trim()) {
      return of([]);
    }
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${'api/heroes'}/?name=${term}`)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="search-component">
  <label for="search-box">Hero Search</label>
  <input #searchBox id="search-box" (input)="search(searchBox.value)" />

  <ul class="search-result">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" >
      <a routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">
        {{hero.name}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Why would I favor an observable for this livesearch in particular?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you use an observable you should "unsubscribe" (generally you unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy, see, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription) using takeUntil. The [pipe async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe), makes the work for you. For me is more "comfortable" using the pipe async aproach, but it's equal valid yours

Comment: You don't need to unsubscribe from http request. It's get value once and unsubscribe automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, here you have a request to the server. It works with `HttpClient` module, and it returns `Observable` value by default.
You can do the same with `Promise`, but should check `Promise` vs `Observable` difference. `Angular` is all about `Observable` and `RxJS`.

For example for that live search an easy reason to use `observable` is cancellable answer, what's impossible to do with promise. `SwitchMap` operator do it for you in the right place.

Secondly, it's the view recalculation with `ChangeDetectionStrategy`. `Async` pipe do the right job and give you the best performance and easy usage.